# What is the best way to retrieve a single folder from a github repository in a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, github, urllib

I need to download a single folder from a github repository in a Python 3 script.

- Listing all raw file URLs to download is tedious and eventual new files would need to be added manually
- Downloading the whole repository as zip takes rather long; there are lots of unneeded files. [This how I do at the moment]

I have read about web services that do what I would need, such as `downgit.github.io`, but the problem is that generating the relevant URL and fetching it via `urllib.request.urlretrive()` downloads the website rather than the actual file.

What can I do? Is there a web service that provides raw file links that I can download as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution: The [`ffspec`](https://github.com/fsspec/filesystem_spec) library may be used to download a single folder from a GitHub repository using Python. See https://sebastianwallkoetter.wordpress.com/2022/01/30/copy-github-folders-using-python/